# Factorization of a polynomial fraction to a certain combinations of other polynomial fractions

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, factorization, algebra

I currently am working on a project for to find some new algebra structures. But I faced with a factorization problem which I cannot come out of it! I could find the lower dimensional of it. But I need a Mathematica codding algorithm for to find the higher dimensional cases. One of my easiest factorization is as what I explain bellow (Which I know its factorization, but I want to re-find it by using Mathematica!):

I need to factorize the following polynomial fraction by using Mathematica

```
F6[x1, y1, x2 , y2, x3 , y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6] = (2 x1 x2 x5 x6 y2 (x2 y1 + x3 (y1 + y2)) y3^2 y4 (x5 y5 +  x4 (y4 + y5)))/((x2 y2 + x1 (y1 + y2)) (x3 y3+ x2 (y2 + y3))^2 (x4 y3 + x5 (y3 + y4))^2 (x5 y4 + x6 (y4 + y5)));
```

to the combination of the following polynomial fractions

```
K1[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3] = ((x2 y2 + x1 (y1 + y2)) (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3)))/(x2 y2 (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3) + x1 (y1 + y2 + y3)));


K2[y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4] = ((x2 y1 + x3 (y1 + y2)) (x3 y2 + x4 (y2 + y3)))/(x3 y2 (x2 y1 + (x3 + x4) (y1 + y2) + x4 y3));


K3[x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4] = ((x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3)) (x4 y4 + x3 (y3 + y4)))/(x3 y3 (x4 y4 + x3 (y3 + y4) + x2 (y2 + y3 + y4)));


K4[ y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5]  = ((x3 y2 + x4 (y2 + y3)) (x4 y3 + x5 (y3 + y4)))/(x4 y3 (x3 y2 + (x4 + x5) (y2 + y3) + x5 y4));


K5[ x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5]  = ((x4 y4 + x3 (y3 + y4)) (x5 y5 + x4 (y4 + y5)))/(x4 y4 (x5 y5 + x4 (y4 + y5) + x3 (y3 + y4 + y5)));


K6[ y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6]  = ((x4 y3 + x5 (y3 + y4)) (x5 y4 + x6 (y4 + y5)))/(x5 y4 (x4 y3 + (x5 + x6) (y3 + y4) + x6 y5));
```

But as I know the answer, so I will write it here and need a codding which can give me this factorization or any other factorization with the above mentioned factors:

The combination is as follows:

```
F6[x1, y1, x2 , y2, x3 , y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6] = ((K1[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3] - 1) (K3[x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4] - 1) (K4[y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5] - 1)(K6[y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6] - 1))/(K1[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3] K3[x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4] K4[y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5] K6[y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6]) = ((K1[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3] - 1)/K1[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3]) ((K3[x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4] - 1)/K3[x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4]) ((K4[y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5] - 1)/K4[y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5]) ((K6[y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6] - 1)/K6[y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6]);
```

I will appreciate a lot if someone helps me to write down a Mathematica codding which is able to give me such combinations of $K1, K2, K3, K4, K5 $ and $K6$.

Here there is another factorization problem in 9 variable (The easiest one!) which I still don't know how it should done!

The question is the same as previous one; We have the following polynomial fraction and wanna to decompose it

```
F9[x1, y1, z1, x2 , y2, z2, x3 , y3, z3, x4, y4, z4, x5, y5, z5, x6, y6, z6] = (2 x1 x2 x5 y2 y5 y6 z2 (x2 y1 y2 z1 + x2 y1 y3 z1 + x3 y1 y3 z1 + x2 y1 y3 z2 + x3 y1 y3 z2 + x3 y2 y3 z2) z3^2 z4 (x4 x5 y4 z4 + x4 x6 y4 z4 + x4 x6 y5 z4 + x4 x6 y4 z5 + x4 x6 y5 z5 +  x5 x6 y5 z5))/((x1 y1 z1 + x1 y1 z2 + x1 y2 z2 + x2 y2 z2) (x2 y2 z2 + x2 y2 z3 + x2 y3 z3 +  x3 y3 z3)^2 (x4 y4 z3 + x4 y5 z3 + x5 y5 z3 + x5 y5 z4)^2 (x5 y5 z4 + x5 y6 z4 + x6 y6 z4 + x6 y6 z5));
```

to the combination of the following polynomial fractions

```
K1[x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3]  = ((x1 y1 z1 + x2 y2 z2 + x1 (y1 + y2) z2) (x2 y2 z2 + x3 y3 z3 + x2 (y2 + y3) z3))/(x2 y2 z2 (x2 y2 z2 + x3 y3 z3 + x2 (y2 + y3) z3 + x1 (y2 z2 + (y2 + y3) z3 + y1 (z1 + z2 + z3))));

K2[y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4] = (((x2 + x3) y1 z1 + x3 (y1 + y2) z2) ((x3 + x4) y2 z2 +  x4 (y2 + y3) z3))/(x3 y2 z2 (x2 y1 z1 + (x3 + x4) (y2 z2 + y1 (z1 + z2)) + x4 (y1 + y2 + y3) z3));


K3[z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4] = ((x2 (y2 + y3) z1 + x3 y3 (z1 + z2)) (x3 (y3 + y4) z2 +  x4 y4 (z2 + z3)))/(x3 y3 z2 (x2 (y2 + y3 + y4) z1 + x3 (y3 + y4) (z1 + z2) + x4 y4 (z1 + z2 + z3)));


K4[x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4]  = ((x2 y2 z2 + x3 y3 z3 + x2 (y2 + y3) z3) (x3 y3 z3 + x4 y4 z4 + x3 (y3 + y4) z4))/(x3 y3 z3 (x3 y3 z3 + x4 y4 z4 + x3 (y3 + y4) z4 + x2 (y3 z3 + (y3 + y4) z4 + y2 (z2 + z3 + z4))));


K5[y2, z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4, x5]  = (((x3 + x4) y2 z2 + x4 (y2 + y3) z3) ((x4 + x5) y3 z3 + x5 (y3 + y4) z4))/(x4 y3 z3 (x3 y2 z2 + (x4 + x5) (y3 z3 +  y2 (z2 + z3)) + x5 (y2 + y3 + y4) z4));


K6[z2, x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4, x5, y5]  = ((x3 (y3 + y4) z2 + x4 y4 (z2 + z3)) (x4 (y4 + y5) z3 + x5 y5 (z3 + z4)))/(x4 y4 z3 (x3 (y3 + y4 + y5) z2 +  x4 (y4 + y5) (z2 + z3) + x5 y5 (z2 + z3 + z4)));


K7[x3, y3, z3, x4, y4, z4, x5, y5, z5]  = ((x3 y3 z3 + x4 y4 z4 + x3 (y3 + y4) z4) (x4 y4 z4 + x5 y5 z5 + x4 (y4 + y5) z5))/(x4 y4 z4 (x4 y4 z4 + x5 y5 z5 + x4 (y4 + y5) z5 + x3 (y4 z4 + (y4 + y5) z5 + y3 (z3 + z4 + z5))));


K8[y3, z3, x4, y4, z4, x5, y5, z5, x6]  = (((x4 + x5) y3 z3 + x5 (y3 + y4) z4) ((x5 + x6) y4 z4 + x6 (y4 + y5) z5))/(x5 y4 z4 (x4 y3 z3 + (x5 + x6) (y4 z4 + y3 (z3 + z4)) + x6 (y3 + y4 + y5) z5));



K9[z3, x4, y4, z4, x5, y5, z5, x6, y6]  = ((x4 (y4 + y5) z3 + x5 y5 (z3 + z4)) (x5 (y5 + y6) z4 +  x6 y6 (z4 + z5)))/(x5 y5 z4 (x4 (y4 + y5 + y6) z3 + x5 (y5 + y6) (z3 + z4) + x6 y6 (z3 + z4 + z5)));
```

The question is the same as the previous one. We want to decompose $F9$ just in terms of $K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6, K7, K8, K9$, which will be our factors.

Please again let me know if the question is not clear.

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Please paste the code rather than pictures of the code.

Comment: I don't know how to put in Mathematica format here! Can you please edit it? Thanks! @BobHanlon

Comment: Convert notebook cells to `InputForm` then copy and paste. Indent four spaces for code block (or use `{}` icon). See [Markdown help](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Comment: Thanks! I think I did it! :) @BobHanlon

Comment: Sorry,  is it possible to have such Mathematica codding which gives me the factorization? @BobHanlon

Comment: How general do you wish the expansion to be?  It appears to me that you're trying to find all polynomial factors of the form `(K+a)^p`, where `a` is a real number and `p` is an integer power.  Is this general enough?

Comment: It can be any composition which just contains $K1, K2, K3, K4, K5, K6$ in it. I mean a composition which we can see all mentioned factors or some of them as a factor of it. In other words $F6$ be divisible by the mentioned factors! @jjc385

Comment: The code in the question immediately following. "The combination is as follows:" is missing a factor of `2` on its right side.

Comment: Yes yes, You are right! But the problem is that my computer can not run your program! Can you please run it for me for $F9$? I am very interested to see that what it will be in $Sl_4$ case!! Thank you very much! @bbgodfrey

Comment: Thank you very much! Sorry can I ask how much RAM do I need for to run it? I wanna buy a second hand laptop with 16 GB RAM! @bbgodfrey

Comment: More than 16GB, I would guess.  But I shall not know until I actually get the F9 answer.

Comment: @bbgodfrey , sorry did it work for $F9$?

Comment: No, it did not.  I shall try a few other options today.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time! I appreciate it a lot! Because I still have no clue on how it will be in $Sl_4$! @bbgodfrey

Comment: I know little about continuous groups of transformations but assume that Sl4 is such a group. Could you say a few words about what you are trying to accomplish? More insight into your ultimate goal might permit me to be more helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry can I have your email address please? @bbgodfrey

Comment: I think I found it! Can I send you email please?@bbgodfrey

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A generalization of the answer to [129970](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/128153/1063) solves the first half of this question in about 70 seconds.

```
tp = Tuples[Range[-1, 1], 6]; tp // Length
(* 729 *)
gp = Map[t1^#[[1]] t2^#[[2]] t3^#[[3]] t4^#[[4]] t5^#[[5]] t6^#[[6]] &, tp].
    Table[Unique["c"], tp // Length];
sol = Flatten@Solve[Table[(f6 == (gp /. {t1 -> k1, t2 -> k2, t3 -> k3, t4 -> k4, 
    t5 -> k5, t6 -> k6})) /. Thread[{x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, y1, y2, y3, y4, y5} -> 
    RandomInteger[{1, 11}, 11]], {n, tp // Length}], 
    List @@ (First@# & /@ (gp /. gp[[1]] -> gp[[1]] z))]);
sol /. Rule[_, 0] -> Nothing
(* {c114 -> -2, c115 -> 2, c123 -> 2, c124 -> -2, c330 -> -2, c331 -> 2, 
    c339 -> 2, c340 -> -2, c357 -> 2, c358 -> -2, c366 -> -2, c367 -> 2, 
    c87 -> 2, c88 -> -2, c96 -> -2, c97 -> 2} *)
Factor[gp /. sol]
(* (2 (-1 + t1) (-1 + t3) (-1 + t4) (-1 + t6))/(t1 t3 t4 t6) *)
```

Answer (score 7):

Rewriting your definitions slightly

```
poly = (2 x1 x2 x5 x6 y2 (x2 y1 + x3 (y1 + y2)) y3^2 y4 (x5 y5 + 
   x4 (y4 + y5)))/((x2 y2 + x1 (y1 + y2)) (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3))^2 (x4 y3 + 
   x5 (y3 + y4))^2 (x5 y4 + x6 (y4 + y5)));

eqns = { 
   K1 == ((x2 y2 + x1 (y1 + y2)) (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3)))/(x2 y2 (x3 y3 + 
     x2 (y2 + y3) + x1 (y1 + y2 + y3))), 
   K2 == ((x2 y1 + x3 (y1 + y2)) (x3 y2 + 
     x4 (y2 + y3)))/(x3 y2 (x2 y1 + (x3 + x4) (y1 + y2) + x4 y3)), 
   K3 == ((x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3)) (x4 y4 + x3 (y3 + y4)))/(x3 y3 (x4 y4 + 
     x3 (y3 + y4) + x2 (y2 + y3 + y4))), 
   K4 == ((x3 y2 + x4 (y2 + y3)) (x4 y3 + 
     x5 (y3 + y4)))/(x4 y3 (x3 y2 + (x4 + x5) (y2 + y3) + x5 y4)), 
   K5 == ((x4 y4 + x3 (y3 + y4)) (x5 y5 + x4 (y4 + y5)))/(x4 y4 (x5 y5 + 
     x4 (y4 + y5) + x3 (y3 + y4 + y5))), 
   K6 == ((x4 y3 + x5 (y3 + y4)) (x5 y4 + 
     x6 (y4 + y5)))/(x5 y4 (x4 y3 + (x5 + x6) (y3 + y4) + x6 y5))
   };
```

Compute GroebnerBasis

```
gb = GroebnerBasis[eqns, {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6}];
```

The remainder gives a representation of poly in terms of K1 .. K6

```
{qs, r} = PolynomialReduce[poly, gb, {x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4, y4, x5, y5, x6}];
```

Where r is your solution in K1 ... K6. This validates correctness:

```
poly == r /. ToRules[And @@ eqns] // Expand
```

Please note, this may take a while, but simplification seems part of your research objective (and you are only asking for ways to code this).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! I even didn't expect that there can be a relation between this question and Groebner Basis! I think it will work. But since morning I am trying to load it! But it seems it needs too much memory! I also bought a student account in Mathematica online, but it also says "This computation has exceeded the memory limit for your plan"! Can I ask that how much memory is enough for to run this program, please? I want to buy another plan from Mathematica online! Thanks!

Comment: It does exceed 16 GB few times, so I guess 32 GB is what you need. Not sure if my config is representative. Also, calculation seems to explode exponentially so before you start spending ... I'm not sure if you can address much larger problems.

Comment: Definitely a very sound approach (I upvoted), and (unfortunately) also one that can chew up a lot of RAM.

Comment: @Daniel Lichtblau Thanks, that is such an honour coming from you. Actually, seeing your comment triggered something in my sub conscience and - after checking - I can tell you that you showed me this approach about two years back ... So a very sound approach indeed!
At the time I was attempting to use ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression`` for an algebraic decomposition. I abandoned that attempt as there was a more general pattern based solutions, but for this one; could the internal compiler optimizer help out?

Comment: I had not considered ``Experimental`OptimizeExpression`` but my feeling is that it is no stronger for this example than rule replacement or use of `PolynomialReduce` without first computing GB.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau Okay, thanks ...

Comment: I just found a computer with 16GB RAM. But I have to wait till Monday! I hope this program will work. If it works then I will be able to finish my project in less than one day! Thanks! @Sander

Comment: Try to get your hands on 32GB, I said it EXCEEDS 16 GB, meaning that it probably will slow down substantially due to memory swaps (I did not time my solution but had it run overnight, swapping could - I don't know the data  intensity of the algorithm behind it but it definitely was not CPU constraint - get it to run for days!! Good luck with you project anyway!

Comment: How is it going?

Comment: That computer also couldn't run it! But I will accept your answer! Because I think it will work! I don't think so I will be able to find such computer! Can I have a request? Can you please do it for me in 9 variable case? If you say yes I will add that case also @Sander

Comment: Sure, happy to try. What do you know about the complexity and hardness of the problem? Out of interest, how did you find the factorisation without MMA?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I added the next problem which consist of 9 variables! (The easiest one between them!). I just do have some perspective of its factorization which can be done like $\frac {(K1 -1)(K9-1)}{K1 K9} \times \frac {(K4-1)(K5-1)(K6-1)}{K4 K5 K6}$. But it is not the answer, the factorization should be something like this. Actually I do use trial and error and some old structures!)) I will appretiate a lot if you can give me the last output of your program for this question. Then I can simplify it in terms of $K_i $'s. I wanna see what will be the output of your program, please. @Sander

Comment: Do you think there is any other way else that using Mathematica? I mean can you believe that it's computable on the paper? @Sander

Comment: I had your 9 variables problem run overnight but had to abort it this morning (as I need my PC for other stuff, sorry). As I eluded to earlier, this looks pretty exponential hence we need to work towards another approach.

Comment: I suggest you do two things: (1) read up on the options available for `GroebnerBasis`: `MonomialOrder`, `CoefficientDomain` and `Method`. They can all have a substantial impact on time needed to arrive at a solution and you need to bring these specifics into the algorithm to ensure an optimal approach: you may solve it that way. If not (2) include the knowledge you have about the problem that drives these settings in a NEW question, label it very specific, like "Optimization of GroebnerBasis" and it will hopefully attract fresh expertise on how to fine tune your use of `GroebnerBasis`.

Comment: MAKE SURE to include the characteristics of your problem so people can use that to address complexity in an appropriate manner and put your problem in a working algorithm (as in how I rewrote them) and tag it "performance optimization".

Comment: I wanna buy a laptop with 16 GB RAM (extendable to 32 GB)! Will your program really work? @Sander

Comment: No! As I stated, the combinatorial complexity grows exponentially with this method. You need to pursue another solution path. I helped you out with the semantics, without restructuring your method, you will crash on the next level. More GB is not the answer.