# Factorization of a fractional multivariate polynomial

Tags: equation-solving, symbolic, polynomials, algebra, factorization

Suppose I have given a fractional multivariate polynomial

```
F2[x1, y1, x2 , y2, x3 , y3, x4] = -((2 x1 x2 x3 x4 y1 y2^2 y3 (x2 y1 + (x3 + x4) (y1 + y2) + x4 y3) (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3) + x1 (y1 + y2 + y3)))/((x2 y2 + x1 (y1 + y2))^2 (x2 y1 + x3 (y1 + y2)) (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3)) (x3 y2 + x4 (y2 + y3))^2));
```

and some other fractional multivariate polynomials

```
K1[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3] = (x2 y2 (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3) + x1 (y1 + y2 + y3)))/((x2 y2 + x1 (y1 + y2)) (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3)));
```

and

```
K2[y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4] = (x3 y2 (x2 y1 + (x3 + x4) (y1 + y2) + x4 y3))/((x2 y1 + x3 (y1 + y2)) (x3 y2 + x4 (y2 + y3)));
```

If I know that it is possible to factorize $F2$ in terms of $K1$ and $K2$ as follows

```
F2[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4] = -2 (K1[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3] K2[y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4] ) (1 - K1[x1, y1, x2, y2, x3, y3]) (1 - K2[y1, x2, y2, x3, y3, x4]);
```

then how can I formulate this factorization in Mathematica?

How could I write a program for to do it? Which tools should I use?

Comment: Why not give a concrete example of a factorable "fractional multivariate polynomial"?

Comment: I couldn't understand your point?! @J.M.

Comment: Something like "an example of a factorable univariate polynomial is $x^2-1=(x-1)(x+1)$"... you might want to talk about what a "fractional multivariate polynomial" is supposed to be for non-experts who might want to try things out anyway.

Comment: Here I have asked a same question with more details. But somehow I think more details is not so useful! http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121921/factorization-of-a-polynomial-fraction-to-a-certain-combinations-of-other-polyno @J.M.

Comment: I'll raise the same question I did on Wolfram Community: What do you find in the documentation when you enter either "factor" or "Factor"?

Comment: Yes that's me in Wolfram Community. Sorry I didn't get your point? Factor doesn't work for multi-univariate rational functions. Now I try "Apart" @DanielLichtblau

Comment: `Factor` works just fine on multivariate rational functions. If you are having trouble actually seeing the separate factors, then use `FactorList`.

Comment: It doesn't work! You see I put main functions in Wolfram Community. I will appretiate if you check them out. Thanks! @DanielLichtblau

Comment: Okay, now at least it is more clear what you are wanting. The subject heading and the original description were quite misleading. What you are after is really a term rewriting, not an algebraic factorization per se. I retracted my "close" vote since the actual problem is neither trivial nor immediate from documentation.

Comment: What do you mean by "close" vote? where? @DanielLichtblau

Comment: No this is a very special problem which has came after many calculations! @DanielLichtblau

Comment: At the bottom of the question there are links "share edit close flag". Notice that "close" is marked with a (3) (as of this writing). It requires 5 to close the question. It had been at 4 and went to 3 when I retracted mine.

Comment: So what is the problem with question being up? I cannot understand! May be it will get some answers!! @DanielLichtblau

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I interpret the question to be, given

```
f2 = -((2 x1 x2 x3 x4 y1 y2^2 y3 (x2 y1 + (x3 + x4) (y1 + y2) + x4 y3) 
    (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3) + x1 (y1 + y2 + y3)))/((x2 y2 + x1 (y1 + y2))^2 
    (x2 y1 + x3 (y1 + y2)) (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3)) (x3 y2 + x4 (y2 + y3))^2));
k1 = (x2 y2 (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3) + x1 (y1 + y2 + y3)))/((x2 y2 + x1 (y1 + y2)) 
    (x3 y3 + x2 (y2 + y3)));
k2 = (x3 y2 (x2 y1 + (x3 + x4) (y1 + y2) + x4 y3))/((x2 y1 + x3 (y1 + y2)) 
    (x3 y2 + x4 (y2 + y3)));
```

express `f2` as a low-order polynomial in `k1` and `k2`.  This can be done as follows.  First, generate a generic low order polynomial.

```
Map[t1^First@# t2^Last@# &, Tuples[Range[0, 3], 2]].Table[Unique["c"], 16]
(* c3 + c7 t1 + c11 t1^2 + c15 t1^3 + c4 t2 + c8 t1 t2 + c12 t1^2 t2 + 
   c16 t1^3 t2 + c5 t2^2 + c9 t1 t2^2 + c13 t1^2 t2^2 + c17 t1^3 t2^2 + 
   c6 t2^3 + c10 t1 t2^3 + c14 t1^2 t2^3 + c18 t1^3 t2^3 *)
```

and then use `SolveAlways`.  After about twenty seconds,

```
Flatten@SolveAlways[f2 == (% /. {t1 -> k1, t2 -> k2}), {x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3}]
(* {c3 -> 0, c4 -> 0, c5 -> 0, c6 -> 0, c11 -> 0, c15 -> 0, c7 -> 0, c12 -> 2, c16 -> 0, 
    c8 -> -2, c10 -> 0, c13 -> -2, c14 -> 0, c17 -> 0, c18 -> 0, c9 -> 2} *)
Factor[%% /. %]
(* -2 (-1 + t1) t1 (-1 + t2) t2 *)
```

which is the desired result.  For completeness,

```
Simplify[f2 == % /. {t1 -> k1, t2 -> k2}]
(* True *)
```

**Much Faster Alternative**

Because `SolveAlways` determines the coefficients `c` for any `{x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3}`, `Solve` must be able to obtain the same values for the coefficients `c` for specific values of `{x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3}`, and much faster.

```
tp = Tuples[Range[0, 3], 2]; tp // Length
(* 16 *)
gp = Map[t1^#[[1]] t2^#[[2]] &, tp].Table[Unique["c"], tp // Length];
Flatten@Solve[Table[(f2 == (gp /. {t1 -> k1, t2 -> k2})) /. 
    Thread[{x1, x2, x3, x4, y1, y2, y3} -> RandomInteger[{1, 7}, 7]], {n, tp // Length}], 
    List @@ (First@# & /@ (gp /. gp[[1]] -> gp[[1]] z))] /. Rule[_, 0] -> Nothing
(* {c12 -> 2, c13 -> -2, c8 -> -2, c9 -> 2} *)
```

as before but three orders of magnitude faster.  Note, however, that this alternative always returns results for `c`, but they are visibly meaningless (random numbers in effect), if the corresponding result from `SolveAlways` is an empty `List`.

Comment: I cannot believe it!! It really works! I don't know how to appreciate what you  did for me! It means a lot for me! You again did a great job! It was a long time that neither me nor any other person was able to produce this program! Now I can extend it! You saved my project again!! It says that after 14 hours I can give +50, I will do it after 14 hours!! Thank you very much! @bbgodfrey

Comment: Can you please let me know if we want to decompose our function, say $f3$ to $k1, k2, k3$; then what should I write in "Map" for $t2^?$ and what can be in my "Range" and also instead of "2" and instead of "16"? I still am not used to "Map"! Thank you very much for your time and your help! @bbgodfrey

Comment: @farrokh  For three functions use `Map[t1^#[[1]] t2^#[[2]] t^#[[3]] &, Tuples[Range[0, 3], 3]].Table[Unique["c"], 64]`  However, note that the number of elements has grown from 16 to 64, so the calculation will be somewhat slower.  As you go to bigger and bigger problems, the calculation could become prohibitively slow.  To avoid this, use whatever other knowledge you have of the problem to reduce the number of elements in the generic polynomial.  By the way, 64 is obtained by `Tuples[Range[0, 3], 3] // Length`.